# What do the Blue soldiers say when they spot you?

Tags: wolfenstein-3d

In Wolfenstein 3D, whenever you alert or get spotted by one of the Blue soldiers with machine guns, they say the same phrase (likely in German since they were Nazi soldiers after all).

If you watch the below video, you can hear what they say (the phrase is said right after the player shoots his gun):

To me, it sounds like they are saying something like *gustavo*, but a German word search for that word doesn't yield anything.

I've played this game for many years and have never known what they said. What is the exact word/phrase they say (preferably in German with an English translation)?

Comment: I am a german native speaker and I can't recognize what he is saying. At first I thought something like a fast spoken ["Gestapo"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gestapo), but after several times I don't think so.

Comment: @Artery I can hear that too, and I would say it's possible that might be what they say.  Kind of like in the tone of "*Secret Police! Stop!*" - but then words would be missing.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

They introduce themselves as '[Schutzstaffel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schutzstaffel)' (*Protection Squadron*), the paramilitary organization better known as the SS. In the [source code](https://github.com/id-Software/wolf3d/blob/master/WOLFSRC/AUDIOSDM.H) as released by id software the sound file is referred to as SCHUTZADSND.

Strangely enough the famous blue sprite doesn't look like any version of the historical SS uniform. This was changed in the Spear of Destiny mission packs, where this enemy type adopted a black uniform. The health definitions in the [source code](https://github.com/id-Software/wolf3d/blob/master/WOLFSRC/WL_ACT2.C) also does confirm these enemy types are meant to be SS troopers:

> 25,  // guards
>       50,   // officer
>       100,  // SS
>   1,    // dogs

Comment: Now that you mention it, I can definitely here "Schutzstaffel!" Like I kind of said in my comment on my question, it's almost like they are yelling "Police!"

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'm German but the only thing I understood was "Toothtrouble" because what they say isn't even close to the German pronounciation of Schutzstaffel.

Comment: It's easier to hear it in this video and the other sounds are included as well: https://youtu.be/VhctmeEebVo?t=9

Answer (score 2):

I think they're definitely saying "Schutzstaffel!". As far as the details on their uniforms; Wolfenstein 3d was a prototype for the game series. As the series expanded leading up to the newest one, Return to Castle Wolfenstein: Operation Resurrection, they did more extensive research on the proper SS uniforms. You notice on Operation Resurrection they're a lot more detailed and a lot more accurate. 
As to what the blue SS soldiers say when they die, it sounds like "Mein leben!" which in German translates to "My life!" 
This was found in urbandictionary.com (link below)
https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Mein+Leben&amp=true